# Load data to ListView HeaderView

Tags: android, listview

I created ListView inside the RelaytiveLayout and the ListView getting data from Url. Then i added Header and footer to this ListView.My HeaderView contains ImageView and TextView. It's working fine. But my doubt is **how to get url data to my HeaderView?**

I added my HeaderView like here:

```
    View headerView = ((LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    list.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Comment: what's the problem here? Do you want to fetch data from a link and load it to the header view? If so, why not use the webview?

Comment: good idea but my listview have two images and two textview.I want to make entire layout is scrollabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `ImageView` and `TextView` from your header like

```
View headerView = ...
ImageView headerImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerImageViewId);
TextView headerTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerTextViewId);
```

Then when you have the data that you get from url, you can update it to the `headerImageView` and `headerTextView`

Comment: If i add headerTextView.setText("text") it shows java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: it means headerTextView is Null